# Vote implementation in parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am stuck for a very long time. I am trying to implement a vote feature in a collection view. If the user taps the button it adds one vote to parse and shows it on the label. My code does that however when I look into the parse dashboard I see that a new row is create and the number of votes is not going into the post [image]

My code for the cell is

```
import UIKit
import ParseUI
import Parse

var votes = [PFObject]()


class NewCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var parseObject = PFObject(className: "Posts")
    @IBOutlet weak var postsImageView: PFImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var postsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var votesLabel:UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        postsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
         print("Passing11")

    }


    @IBAction func vote(sender: AnyObject) {

                if let votes = parseObject.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
                    parseObject.setObject(votes + 1, forKey: "votes")
                    parseObject.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
                    votesLabel?.text = "\(votes + 1) votes"
                    print("Passing22")
                }
                else
                {
                    parseObject.setObject(1, forKey: "votes")
                    parseObject.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
                    votesLabel?.text = "1 votes"
                     print("Passing33")
                }
            }}
```

and collection view is

```
        if let votes = parseObject.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
            cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votes) votes"
        }
        else
        {
            cell.votesLabel?.text = "0 votes"
        }
    return cell

    }
```

How can I make it work? Thank you.

Comment: does your parse object "parseObject" contains objectId ?

Comment: By the way, there is a function on `PFObject` called `incrementKey`, so you can say `parseObject.incrementKey("votes")` and then save the object

Comment: Is the button to vote in every collection view cell? And if so, is it defined in a custom collection view cell class?

Comment: I have updated my question  and for increment key I have replaced it to         if let votes = parseObject.incrementKey("votes") as? Int {
 code and it still does not change and a warning saying        Cast from Void to unrelated type Int always fails

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember in my Parse project. If you need to retrieve and update an existing row in Parse you need to create a ***PFQuery*** object first and retrieve the desired row using that query object. And then you can update its "vote" or whatever attribute value you want to. Kindly try that.